# Passing a value to onPress to trigger a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, onpress

```
  const change = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    //Firebase.database().ref(`userSubject/${subjectTaken.user}/${subjectTaken.id}/topics/${name}/`).update({"completed": !completed})
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.page}  >
      <Header type="dark-profile" title={subjectTaken.name} desc="Here is your progress. You can do this!" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}/>
      <View>
        {topic.map(item => {
          if(item.completed === true) {
            return <TodoBox text={item.lesson} type={true} onPress={() => console.log("YEY")} />
          } else {
            const name = item.lesson
            return (
              
              <TodoBox text={item.lesson} type={false} onPress={(name) => {this.change(item.lesson)}} />
            )
          }
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I am wondering how i can pass the variable item.lesson to the function that i inserted on onpress... log gives me undefined why

Comment: can you add more of the code? it seems that the change handler you included is allocated within the render method and is not the class member function you are calling via this.change

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, you are passing `name` as a parameter, so the function does not know about `item`.

Also, it looks like the `onChange` function requires an `event` as a parameter. So, changing the following line:

```
<TodoBox text={item.lesson} type={false} onPress={(name) => {this.change(item.lesson)}} />
```

to this:

```
<TodoBox text={item.lesson} type={false} onPress={(e) => {this.change(e)}} />
```

might fix this.

Finally, please try to the complete code if possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).